Can you make a csv.DictReader object subscriptable in Python?
So I'm trying to work with a CSV and reorganize the data using a DictReader. I keep trying different things to change the keys or values, but every time the terminal throws me a TypeError saying 'DictReader' object is not subscriptable.
test_data.csv:
Name,number,Colors
John,2,blue
Logan,3,red
Jimmy,4,green
Logan,6,green
Steven,8,orange

and my code:
import csv

my_dictionary = csv.DictReader(open('test_data.csv'))
for row in my_dictionary:
   print(my_dictionary['Name'])

I would expect the output to be something like:
John, Logan, Jimmy, Logan, Steven
But I just keep getting an error instead, help?

You want row['Name'] for that.  There's not much point in a for loop if you aren't going to use the variable it assigns!

I recommend, reader = csv.DictReader(...). Then for row in reader:, then you can use row['Name]'. Right now you have, analogously, reader['Name'], which explains the error: you cannot get a subscript (index/key) of the DictReader.
